# many-to-many-to-many embedded form

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine

I've three simple tables (race, judge, athlete) where columns are id and name.

There are other two tables (race_judge and race_athlete) where I connect a race to many judge and a race to many athletes in the frontend app through embedded form as explained in [Advanced Forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms); these two tables have some extra fields (like judge notes on a race and athlete race number) that can be filled in in an embedded form.

Now I want to build an embedded form for the last table "race_judge_athlete" where every single judge attending a race can give a vote to every athlete attending that race and I'd like to fill the numbers in a single form.

How would I do that using symfony+doctrine forms?

**Update** : when I insert a new race (through RaceForm) judge and athletes are automatically added in race_judge and race_athlete (if selected from the choice widget) thanks to the relation in Athlete and Judge models, but this doesn't happen on race_judge_athlete.

---

Here is the schema.yml:

```
Race:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
Athlete:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
  relations:
    RaceAthlete:
      foreignAlias: RaceAthlete
      class: Race
      refClass: RaceAthlete
      local: athlete_id
      foreign: race_id 
Judge:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
  relations:
    RaceJudge:
      foreignAlias: RaceJudge
      class: Race
      refClass: RaceJudge
      local: judge_id
      foreign: race_id

RaceJudge:
  columns:
    race_id: integer
    judge_id: integer
    judge_notes: string
  relations:
    Race:
      class: Race
      local: race_id
    Judge:
      class: Judge
      local: judge_id
RaceAthlete:
  columns:
    race_id: integer
    athlete_id: integer
    athlete_number: integer
  relations:
    Race:
      class: Race
      local: race_id
    Athlete:
      class: Athlete
      local: athlete_id

RaceJudgeAthlete:
  columns:
    race_id: integer
    judge_id: integer
    athlete_id: integer
    score: double
  relations:
    Race:
      class: Race
      local: race_id
    Judge:
      class: Judge
      local: judge_id
    Athlete:
      class: Athlete
      local: athlete_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a quick hack that works, but it is as ugly as hell!
I'm still looking for a clean implementation, but for now this will do.

In RaceForm.class.php I override the doSave function this way:
I get RaceJudge and RaceAthlete collections just saved by the doSave in RaceForm and create the missing collection manually, delete the actual RaceJudgeAthlete collection and save the manually create one in the emptied RaceJudgeAthlete collection.

Here is the code:

```
    protected function doSave($con = null)
    {
        $this->saveRaceJudgeList($con);
        $this->saveRaceAthleteList($con);

        parent::doSave($con);
        $this->saveRaceJudgeAthlete();
    }

    public function saveRaceJudgeAthlete()
    {
        $race = $this->getObject();
        $RaceJudgeAthlete_collection = new Doctrine_Collection('RaceJudgeAthlete');
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($race->RaceJudge as $judge)
        {
            foreach ($race->RaceAthlete as $athlete)
            {
                $RaceJudgeAthlete_collection[$i]->setRaceId($race->getId());
                $RaceJudgeAthlete_collection[$i]->setJudgeId($judge->judge_id);
                $RaceJudgeAthlete_collection[$i]->setAthleteId($athlete->athlete_id);

                $i++;
            }
        }

        $race->RaceJudgeAthlete->delete();
        $race->RaceJudgeAthlete = $RaceJudgeAthlete_collection;
        $race->RaceJudgeAthlete->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it that way? I have a similar case and it works for me.

```
Race:
  columns:
  name: string(255)

Athlete:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
  relations:
    Races:
      class: Race
      refClass: RaceAthlete
      foreignAlias: RaceAthleteList
      local: athlete_id
      foreign: race_id 

Judge:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
  relations:
    Races:
      class: Race
      refClass: RaceJudge
      foreignAlias: RaceJudgeList
      local: judge_id
      foreign: race_id

RaceJudge:
  columns:
    race_id: integer
    judge_id: integer
    judge_notes: string
  relations:
    Race:
      class: Race
      local: race_id
    Judge:
      class: Judge
      local: judge_id

RaceAthlete:
  columns:
    race_id: integer
    athlete_id: integer
    athlete_number: integer
  relations:
    Race:
      class: Race
      local: race_id
    Athlete:
      class: Athlete
      local: athlete_id

RaceJudgeAthlete:
  columns:
    race_id: integer
    judge_id: integer
    athlete_id: integer
    score: double
  relations:
    Race:
      local: race_id
      foreign: id
    Judge:
      local: judge_id
      foreign: id
    Athlete:
      local: athlete_id
      foreign: id
```

HTH

Comment: In your schema you only change the foreignAlias, and this doesn't work: it updates only RaceAthlete and RaceJudge, as my schema